# rake db:structure:dump fails under PostgreSQL / Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I get this error message:

```
pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "demo_db")
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.
rake aborted!
Error dumping database

Tasks: TOP => db:structure:dump
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This used to work under Rails 3.1. I'm using Rails 3.2.3 and PostgreSQL 9.0.5. Other tasks like db:migrate or db:rollback work just fine.

Comment: see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13733565/168143

Comment: John, thanks but my problem was different. See my accepted solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to dbenhur I found the issue. I have a space in the path of my filename.
Changing line 392 of `activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake` to

```
pg_dump -i -s -x -O -f '#{filename}' #{search_path} #{abcs[Rails.env]['database']}
```

(adding the single quotes around `#{filename}`) fixes the issue.

Comment: @KonstantinGredeskoul the latest source uses [`Shellwords.escape`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L428) on the filename and database name, (but, curiously, not the search_path); so it's much better now. Though really using [`Open3::capture2`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2) with array args is generally safer than [`Kernel::\``](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60)

Comment: Thanks, I did research for given string. And for me it doesn't work because PATH in spring's environment did not contain path to pg_dump.

Answer (score 7):

The `pg_dump` command is executed in [activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake at line 428](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L428).

```
`pg_dump -i -s -x -O -f #{Shellwords.escape(filename)} #{search_path} #{Shellwords.escape(config['database'])}`
```

Try setting a breakpoint there and seeing what actual command is being run.

All those options are valid for Pg9.0.x, so I suspect there's something funny in `abcs[Rails.env]['schema_search_path']` which confuses psql's option parsing. Note the `search_path` construction doesn't quote the `--schema` argument, so a `search_path_part` with an embedded space will parse as a partial schema name followed by a word which isn't preceded by an option, so psql will interpret it as a database name, then complain when it gets to the real database name later.

Comment: Thanks, using this technique I found the bug (missing single quotes around the filename). See my response.

Answer (score 1):

I had a simillar problem with db:structure:dump on my setup. Rails 3.2.11 + JRuby 1.7.1[1.8 mode] Postgresql 9.1.7.

The only thing which really helped was downgrading activerecord_jdbc_adapter from version 1.2.5 to 1.2.2.

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', '1.2.2'
gem "activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter", '1.2.2'
```

Hope it will help anybody.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this (dark) issue by creating a new app with postgresql as database (`rails new MyApp -d postgresql`), and then move all my old app files (/app folder, migrations, and some /config files) to new one. Now when I run rake db:migrate, there are no pg_dump error. I hope this helps someone.