# Error when doing rake db:migrate on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, rake, database-migration

when doing

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

all migrations are performed and then, at the end I always get following message:

`/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake: No such file or directory - pg_dump -i -s -x -O -f /app/db/structure.sql  dan79p98fykovu`

I can't add pg_dump to PATH on Heroku.
How to deal with this?

Comment: What's in your Gemfile? It might be that you have a gem that is trying to execute some code after the migrations that depends on that pg_dump. There used to be an error message I would get after every rake task run that had to do with Test::Unit being installed when I was using RSpec for testing - somewhat of a similar problem

Comment: Take a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248893/rake-dbstructuredump-fails-under-postgresql-rails-3-2

It may be that you are using a version of Rails that has this bug/issue - what version are you using?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The issue is that rails is trying to dump a new `structure.sql` once the migration is complete, and failing because `pg_dump` is not present. It's pointless to generate a new structure.sql for a deployed app, so the best solution is to tell rails not to.

Edit your `Rakefile` and override the task. Adding the following line at the end of it should do it:

```
Rake::Task["db:structure:dump"].clear if Rails.env.production?
```

Comment: n.b.: this only happens when using structure.sql, and not when using schema.rb

Comment: Wouldn't `unless Rails.env.development?` be a better condition?

Comment: Why `pg_dump` is not present?

Comment: It's not needed by a production application.