# Rails Postgres deploying to heroku issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am having difficulty pushing my most recent rails 3.2 app to heroku. I have been pushing to it previously with no problems, the most recent things that I have done since this last working commit was added a hstore column for postgres and a coupld of models. These all work perfectly on my and other computers.

On running

heroku run rake db:migrate I get the following output:

```
james@James-PC:~/tendersave$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.1
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake: No such file or directory - pg_dump -i -s -x -O -f /app/db/structure.sql  d36q1tfb51f169
```

Note the error on the last line

Also on running heroku run db:setup I get this:

```
james@James-PC:~/tendersave$ heroku run rake db:setup
Running `rake db:setup` attached to terminal... up, run.1
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
d36q1tfb51f169 already exists
sh: psql: not found
```

Again where there is an error on the last line.

then if I check heroku's logs I get the following (I presume because it hasnt run the migrations):

```
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 203.173.199.11 at 2012-09-22 02:24:06 +0000
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ProposalsController#index as HTML
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered proposals/index.html.erb within layouts/application (65.2ms)
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 295ms
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "proposals" does not exist
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"proposals"'::regclass
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"proposals"'::regclass
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:     <th></th>
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:   </tr>
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     18: 
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     19: <% @proposals.each do |proposal| %>
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:   <tr>
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:     <td><%#= proposal.active %></td>
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:     <td><%= proposal.type %></td>
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/proposals_controller.rb:14:in `index'
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/proposals/index.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_proposals_index_html_erb__922970733135020301_38000420'
2012-09-22T02:24:06+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: for the pg_dump issue see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13733565/13989

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I simply went through my git from when it worked, and incrementally added the new features and was able to locate the problem

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that you have outstanding migrations you have not run.

Try `heroku run rake db:migrate`. That should clear up the `relations do not exist` error.

For the rest, they are warnings. You can ignore them, but you are seeing that because probably the `vendor/plugins` folder in your project is non-empty, and when Rails 4 arrives, that would be deprecated.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, but unfortunately I get the error above from running rake db:migrate and then it seems that the database is not migrated properly

Comment: My bad! Have you enable HStore in Heroku? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/is-hstore-available

Answer (score 0):

For future browsers, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413306/error-when-doing-rake-dbmigrate-on-heroku) answered it for me. Just add this to the bottom of your Rakefile:

```
Rake::Task["db:structure:dump"].clear unless Rails.env.development?
```