# what is the meaning of the pg_dump and pg_restore errors

Tags: heroku

While I trying to upload database to the heroku, I hav eget this errors `env: pg_dump: no such file or directory and env: pg_restore no such file and directory`. What is the meaning of the this errors ? How can I fix these errors to load database to the heroku ?

Comment: They mean that the file, as you specified it with a path and a name, couldn't be found. If you'd like more help, could you please provide some details, like what exact commands did you type in?

Comment: @mbratch heroku pg:transfer -f ... -t ....

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the :sql dump_format instead of schema.rb?

If so, see your solution here:
[Error when doing rake db:migrate on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413306/error-when-doing-rake-dbmigrate-on-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same errors using pg_transfer. Turns out that the postgresql client tools weren't installed. You can install them with:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
```