# ubuntu `env: ‘pg_dump’: No such file or directory` error

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

The pg_dump environment variable or the file is missing from ubuntu 16.10. After running and installing `sudo apt-get install postgresql-client` (see [what is the meaning of the pg_dump and pg_restore errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760059/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-pg-dump-and-pg-restore-errors)) the error still persists. What environment variable or packages do I have to install to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I resolved the issue. I checked for the version of pg_dump `pg_dump --version`. If pg_dump isn't installed, install using 
`sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-common`