# error with pg_dump when using heroku pg:pull

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04.4 virtual machine on vagrant. Postgresql 9.5

I am trying to use Heroku pg:pull command to download heroku database to the vm. I got the following error:

```
env: ‘pg_dump’: No such file or directory
pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)
```

I have tried various approaches including [installing/updating postgresql-client-common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347234/ubuntu-env-pg-dump-no-such-file-or-directory-error), uninstalling and reinstall the client,  uninstalling and reinstalling PSQL & Heroku, and I've looked all over for the appropriate folder.

Wondering if there is something specific to my setup that is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Heroku CLI; this was just fixed. https://github.com/heroku/cli/pull/1074