# pg_dump error "bash: /usr/bin/pg_dump: No such file or directory"

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, pg-dump

I've been running pgcli for some time and have just started trying to back-up my database. I've tried running pg_dump, but have been having various problems. When I enter this into the CLI:

```
pg_dump --version
```

I get the response:

```
bash: /usr/bin/pg_dump: No such file or directory
```

I've tried installing postgresql-client, as per:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-common
```

But I get the same results whenever I try to use the pg_dump command. I don't know where to begin to resolve this.

(I've picked up the above ideas from previous stack threads, eg: [what is the meaning of the pg_dump and pg_restore errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760059/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-pg-dump-and-pg-restore-errors?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Comment: Postgres version? Where did you get the Postgres packages to begin with and how did you install them? Do you have more then instance of Postgres installed? What does `whereis pg_dump` show?

Comment: What does `which -a pg_dump` show?

Comment: /usr/bin/pg_dump @jjanes (sorry for the delay. I had to re-install postgresql as I'd broken something. Been trying to figure things out since)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, (This is probably a moot point now, because I've removed and reinstalled postgresql - ```whereis pg_dump``` returns:
```pg_dump: /usr/bin/pg_dump /usr/share/man/man1/pg_dump.1.gz```
I've also tried:
```psql --version``` returns:
```psql (PostgreSQL) 13.1 (Ubuntu 13.1-1.pgdg18.04+1)```
Although, ```pg_dump --version``` returns:
```pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 10.15 (Ubuntu 10.15-1.pgdg18.04+1)```

Comment: So is it working?

Comment: It's solved the problem I had where I got "No such file or directory". I'm now back trying to figure out my original problem, which is that I get this message: ```server version: 12.5 (Ubuntu 12.5-1.pgdg16.04+1); pg_dump version: 10.15 (Ubuntu 10.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ```. I've tried to update my postgresql, but I seem to now have two versions of pg_dump on file: ```/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_dump``` , and 
```/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_dump```. Every time I try to use pg_dump, it reverts to version 10. Trying to figure out why/how to get it to use the version 12 I have installed.